# how can i get the sum of two colums realtime

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have the following

```
+----------+----------+
| a        | b        |
| numeric  | numeric  |
+----------+----------+
| 10       | 10       |
+----------+----------+
| 10       | 10       |
+----------+----------+
```

I want to have something like that

`select *, a+b as mes
from maths;`

but to have a `column sum` and evrytime the `columns a and b` get update calculate the new sum in columns sum

i try this and i get the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyARC.png)

Comment: MySQL and psql don't belong together. You tagged both. MySQL is a database management system (DBMS), PostgreSQL is another. Psql ist PostgreSQL's frontend. So what DBMS are you actually using?

Comment: i thouth the have similar syntax sorry i will chnage that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for generated column in PostgreSQL is:

```
alter table maths add column kostas int generated always as (a + b) stored;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7f328dbdb991e68b46a8292bf7c480ab

Comment: Thanks so much for the link! it's realy usefull

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a generated column:

```
alter table maths add column mes int generated always as (a + b);
```

I am assuming the columns are `int`.  Use whatever type is appropriate.

Comment: i get a syntax error in 'as' i uplaod a new pic for you to check

Comment: @kostasvythoulkas . . . In Postgres, that needs to be `generated always as`.